# C# List of objects binary search with a comparer

Tags: c#, list, binary-search

I have an object named Artist.

```
public class Artist
{
    public string artistID { get; set; }
    public string artistName { get; set; }

    public Artist(string artistID, string artistName)
    {
        this.artistID = artistID;
        this.artistName = artistName;

    }

    public Artist()
    {
    }
    public Artist(string artistID)
    {
        this.artistID = artistID;
    }
```

Which has a custom Comparer like this:

```
public class CompareArtists : IComparer<Artist>
{

  public int Compare(Artist x, Artist y)
  {
      if (x.artistID == null) return -1;
      if (y.artistID == null) return 1;

    return String.Compare(x.artistID, y.artistID);
   }

}
```

I am trying to see whether an artist is contained in my list of artists in the main program. And I am doing that like this:

```
Artist tempArtist = new Artist(user[1]);
Artist result = new Artist();

position = artists.BinarySearch(tempArtist, dc);
result = artists.ElementAt(position);
                       users.ElementAt(counter).favoriteArtists.Add(result,Int32.Parse(user[2]));
```

The result of the binarysearch, is a negative number which from what I read on MSDN, is the complement of the next largest index. And it is shown when no results were found. However, I am 100% certain that the item I am searching for in my artists list does actually exist there. 
When I use a linear method, e.g. artists.Single or artists.Find, I get a result.

Do you see anything wrong with my comparer or the way I use binary search?

ps: dc is my comparer: CompareArtists dc = new CompareArtists();
and user[] is an array of strings that were split from a line I read with stream reader. it cotains the artist ID at [1]
thanks in advance

Comment: Is your list sorted? Because you can use `BinarySearch` on only a sorted list.

Comment: Also note that your comparer does the wrong thing if it's presented with two artists *both* of whom have a null ID. It should return 0 in that case.

Comment: The list was generated sequentially by reading a file where the IDs are actually ordered. So I would say yes. If that is what you mean

Comment: What is dc? [Dinocomparer?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort your list before `BinarySearch`, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Searches the **entire sorted** List for an element using the specified comparer and returns the zero-based index of the element.

```
artists.Sort(new CompareArtists());
position = artists.BinarySearch(tempArtist, dc);
```

Also you should use same comparer in `Sort` and `BinarySearch` to make it work

Comment: You were all right, I imagined that because the list was generated sequentially, it would actually be ordered. But upon sorting the artists list, my code works.

I am confused, but it works.

Comment: Quick followup. I was actually comparing them as string, in my sequential generation they were ordered as Integers. As strings, the ordering is different. That is why it did not work.